# Read word document (*.doc) content with tables etc

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I have a word document (2003). I am using Powershell to parse the content of the document.
The document contains a few lines of text at the top, a dozen tables with differing number of columns and then some more text.

I expect to be able to read the document as something like the below:

1. Read document (make necessary objects etc)
2. Get each line of text
3. If not part of a table, process as text and Write-Output
4. else
5. If part of a table
6. Get table number (by order) and parse output based on columns
7. end if

Below is the powershell script that I have begun to write:

```
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$objWord.Visible = $false
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($filename)
$paras = $objDocument.Paragraphs
foreach ($para in $paras) 
{ 
    Write-Output $para.Range.Text
}
```

I am not sure if Paragraphs is what I want. Is there anything more suitable for my purpose?
All I am getting now is the entire content of the document. How do I control what I get. Like I want to get a line, be able to determine if it is part of a table or not and take an action based on what number table it is.

Comment: Word documents aren't organized in lines. Please take a step back and describe the problem you're trying to solve rather than what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: Sure - thanks for responding...

So I have this word document that contains some text and about 5 or 6 tables. Each table has a varying number of columns from 2 to 6. The first row in each table describes the header.

What I am trying to accomplish is (using Powershell) to read the document, parse the content of the tables and output sql statements that can be run separately against an Oracle database. 

Now I have many such documents and each of them is similar in structure. But each may have more or less rows in the tables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enumerate the tables in a Word document via the [`Tables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb212166%28v=office.12%29.aspx) collection. The [`Rows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb212166%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [`Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb215428%28v=office.12%29.aspx) properties will allow you to determine the number of rows/columns in a given table. Individual cells can be accessed via the [`Cell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb211844%28v=office.12%29.aspx) object.

Example that will print the value of the cell in the last row and last column of each table in the document:

```
$wd = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$wd.Visible = $true
$doc = $wd.Documents.Open($filename)
$doc.Tables | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Cell($_.Rows.Count, $_.Columns.Count).Range.Text
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have one question - how do I know I am inside a table in order to call the table related logic? Is there like a isTable() construct?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. The `Tables` collection has all tables in the document and nothing else. When you access an object from that collection, that object is a table.

Comment: hmm - I think I now understand what you said. I was trying to read all text in a sequential manner, regardless of whether it is a table or not - and if it a table then I wanted to call the table logic. But I need not do it that way. Using the tables collection seems cleaner. Thank you very much.

Comment: For the record, to determine if you are in a table, use the boolean  "Selection.Information(wdWithInTable)". (6 years late)